# What determines which number spawns?

Tags: 16384-hex

Ìn [16384 Hex](http://rudradevbasak.github.io/16384_hex/), the number that appears on the board when you make a move is usually 1, but sometimes it is 2 or 4.

What determines the next number that will appear or is it simply random?

Comment: How many of these 2048 clones are there still?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the source code of the game (file "game_manager.js", inside the `GameManager.prototype.addRandomTile` function):

```
var value = (Math.random() < 0.75 ? 1 : (Math.random() < 0.75 ? 2 : 4) );
```

Which works out to:

- 75% of the time, it adds a 1, giving a 3 in 4 chance.
- 75% of the remainder, it adds a 2, giving a 3 in 16 chance.
- The rest of the time, it adds a 4, giving a 1 in 16 chance.